# Echoing un-escaped HTML

Tags: php

Very unusual question.

I came across some code some years in the pass that was including conditions and normal PHP syntax while echoing all content.

My question is how is that Technic/syntax called. I have been googling with some very broad terms and can't find what im looking for.

If my memory is correct, The code I viewed long time ago had un-escaped HTML and it was not required to start and stop PHP processing with `<?php` `?>`

I Have a method within a class called `Template\Labels::User()`
the only purpose of that method is to echo the proper html to create a label within my webapp so that the pages are lighten of code and clear to anyone viewing the code.

Id like to avoid, having to `<?php` `?>` for very simple `boolean` `if`

Any one know what I am looking for ?

```
static function User($UserObj,$isLink = true){
    ?>
    <div class="image label bg-purple" style="margin: 4px;">
        <?php if($isLink){
            ?><a href=""><?php
        } ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $UserObj -> ProfilePicture; ?>" style="height: 2em;" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        <label style="font-size: 90%"><?php echo $UserObj->FirstName{0}.$UserObj->LastName{0}; ?></label>
        <?php if($isLink){
            ?></a><?php
        } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

---

Edited

After some more research by going through PHP documentation on Operator
I found Nowdoc string quoting

Can someone shed some light onto `Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc. The construct is ideal for embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for escaping. It shares some features in common with the SGML`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: I didn't understand the images but I will try to help

Comment: Why not put the real code here if you have it?

Comment: @JackSiro Your right, its late didn't though about it. Just updated question with real code

Comment: `it was not required to start and stop PHP processing with <?php ?>` as far as I know that is not possible with HTML in the file too.  It may have been a template system, some of them include logic and even loops.  They are like a mini-language.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I would certenaly think the same thing too, But I am absolutely sure that it was being echo directly and not processed by a template class or anything as it was a single PHP file with no includes,   but I think there was a HTML content EndOfLine char

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I think your right, its not possible, I may be refering to Nowdoc string quoting  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: I am familure with them `<<<FOO   .. $var ... FOO;` - This is actually a HEREDOC,  NOWDOC is like this `<<<'FOO'....FOO;` - the HEREDOC (without the `'`) act like double quotes `"` for variable interpolation (value replacement).  The NOWDOC with the `'` is just like using single quotes (surprise, surprise). - I can see how you could be confused by these, you can only use things that you can use in double quotes. so only things that are "variable-like"  You can use `" {$this->foo()} "` for method calls etc, that dont normally work.

Comment: Coincidentally I learned about these in one of my many attempts at making a template engine.  But it wasn't being used the same way you describe. I used the NOWDOC version (no PHP variables) for HTML output or string chunks that were in the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Its good that you added code to your question so that we can all see what you are dealing with here. Now to me what I understand with your question is that you want to avoid using php tags to echo some html code based on if condition.

```
<?php 
    static function User($UserObj,$isLink = true){
        $html = '<div class="image label bg-purple" style="margin: 4px;">';
        if($isLink) $html .= '<a href="">';
        $html .= '<img src="'.@$UserObj->ProfilePicture.'" style="height: 2em;" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">';
        $html .= '<label style="font-size: 90%">'.@$UserObj->FirstName[0].@$UserObj->LastName[0].'</label>';
        if($isLink) $html .= '</a>';
        echo $html;
    }
?>
```

In my thinking I thought you should just have to run php tags once and use a simple variable to add your html code to so that you can print at the end of the function.

Comment: I think this should answer his question

Comment: It technically works, and does what I need, But not what I was asking for, Although I now think that what im asking is not possible.  and what I though is called Nowdoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: Okay I get you @NicolasRacine. You simply don't want to use php code in your code over and again. Well then just appreciate my effort with an upvote

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand some of your images but all the same your issue is printing unescaped html in PHP. In other words you want to have raw html.

There are two functions am thinking of right now which you can use depending on your desired output: *html_entity_decode()* and *htmlentities()*.

**html_entity_decode()** is the opposite of **htmlentities()** in that it converts all HTML entities in the string to their applicable characters.

```
<?php     $orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>d
$a = htmlentities($orig);
$b = html_entity_decode($a);
echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot
echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>
?>
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode

I hope this helps solve your issue of unescaped html.

Comment: this require me to escape to put conditions whether I use ternary operator or if statement

Comment: and htmlentities are more or less if you want to put some something that need to be escaped in HTML, not in php.  My question is about escaping html to by syntactical correct in PHP

Comment: Am sorry I wrote this answer before you update your question with your real code. Let me do another answer if you don't mind